# Trouble using the Insert Into Syntax in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

On this site (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) it says that I can use the SQL `Insert` statement using the Syntax:

```
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

I tried doing this as follows:

```
create table Trade
(
TradeId INT PRIMARY KEY, -- define a coolumn of type int, primary key can't be null
Symbol varchar(20) NOT NULL, --define a column of type varchar. Not Null indicates that this column must always have a value
TradeAmount decimal(15, 3), -- total digits are 15, 3 or which are decimal points
Filled BIT NOT NULL default(0), -- we specify a default of 0 on the column
)
Go


Insert into Trade  VALUES('GOOG',10.235785,1)
```

However, I get the Error "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition" and am unsure why this is the case.

Thanks

Comment: [Bad habits to kick: using SELECT * / omit the column list](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/10/bad-habits-to-kick-using-select-omitting-the-column-list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You didn't define the first field as autoincremental, so if you don't send it, table is expecting 4 fields and you are only sending 3.

This should work:

```
Insert into Trade  VALUES(1,'GOOG',10.235785,1)
```

Or you can create the table in this way, adding `IDENTITY(1,1)` (for sql-server):
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp

```
create table Trade
(
TradeId INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, -- define a coolumn of type int, primary key can't be null
Symbol varchar(20) NOT NULL, --define a column of type varchar. Not Null indicates that this column must always have a value
TradeAmount decimal(15, 3), -- total digits are 15, 3 or which are decimal points
Filled BIT NOT NULL default(0), -- we specify a default of 0 on the column
)
Go
```

Comment: yes @Ganesh_Devlekar, because that the OP want it in his question

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can describe columns directly before VALUES sequence:

```
INSERT INTO Trade (Symbol, TradeAmount, Filled) VALUES (
    ('GOOG', 10, 1),
    ('MSFT', 7 , 0)
)
```

In this case you'll not need to manage the IDENTITY value by yourself, SQL Server will increase it automatically for each new row.